# October Media Manager 504 Gateway Time-out in Nginx when connecting to AWS

Tags: nginx, aws-sdk, octobercms

I have a very strange problem that is affecting the OctoberCMS Media Manager on all new Ubuntu server installations I have tried.

I have the prerequisite settings in `filesystem.php`

```
'default' => 's3',

'cloud' => 's3',

's3' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key'    => 'key',
    'secret' => 'secret',
    'region' => 'ap-southeast-1',
    'bucket' => 'bucket-name',
],
```

With these settings, it works perfectly on any of my old AWS server instances or on my development machine. I go to the Media Manager in the OctoberCMS backend and I see what's in the S3 bucket. No problems.

But on every single new Ubuntu instance I have tried installing on AWS today (I tried several, in different regions just to be sure) I am getting the same problem:

`504 Gateway Time-out`

`nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)`

All of the Ubuntu instances (working and non-working) are 16.04 with the latest LEMP stack. Increasing the timeout settings makes no difference except it takes longer for the timeout message to appear. Something this simple shouldn't be taking that long on a fresh install with nothing else running anyway. And, indeed, the same thing takes seconds on my old instances and my development machine.

I obviously have `October.Drivers` installed for the AWS-SDK packages.

I must be missing something obvious. Can anyone think what it may be?

**UPDATES**

- This is definitely not a firewall issue (UFW or AWS)
- The AWS CLI tools, installed on the same server work just fine
- There's nothing in the OctoberCMS log or the PHP error log and the only thing in the nginx log is the fact that there was a timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after a day of trying all sorts of weird and wonderful things and trying to get the new server configured exactly the same as the old server, I narrowed the problem down to one difference, which was the absence of the `php7.0-xml` package.

Once I installed this, everything worked.